# SDK 5.2.0 - LaunchLogo.png doesn't work

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, launch-screen

Trying to get the LaunchLogo.png to work, following [this](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Launch_Files)

My tiapp.xml:

```
<use-app-thinning>true</use-app-thinning>
<enable-launch-screen-storyboard>true</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
```

In `app/assets/iphone` I have all five LaunchLogo*.png.

In the project root I have a DefaultIcon.png.

According to the docs, it will use LaunchLogo*.png instead of DefaultIcon.png for the launch screen. However, a clean build and install on the iPad device gives me DefaultIcon.png on the launch screen.

Can't get it to work. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, on the bottom of the release note:

> iOS Launch Logo Caching Issue
>
> Launch logo updates are not reflected when rebuilding the app. iOS caches launch screens to a PNG file that appears to only be invalidated by restarting the iOS. The following changes have no effect: uninstalling the app, cleaning the Titanium app and rebuilding, and removing the cached image from the hard drive. Upon installing the updated app, it writes a new PNG file to cache of the old launch screen. It appears iOS keeps the cached launch screen in memory despite the app is not running. The only way to show the updated launch logo is to restart the simulator and/or device. Users should see a warning about this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. I was able to successfully build it on my machine. The output in question is:

    [WARN]  If this app has been previously installed on this simulator, you may need restart it to see the latest launch logo
    [WARN]  iOS renders and caches the launch screen to a PNG image that seems to only be invalidated by restarting iOS

Comment: Also see [the notes on this blog post](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/titanium-5-2-0-launch-files-ipad-pro-slide-over-and-split-view/#dealing-with-launch-file-cache) on flushing the launch image cache.